# scoreloop get score of current user not working

Tags: android, scoreloop

I want to get the score of the current user in scoreloop . but i don't know how is the logic.

I tried :

```
scoresController.setRangeLength(1);  
scoresController.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession().getUser());
```

But it don't get the current user. it returned someone else. as i undestand the setRangeLength return the number of users i need and loadRangeForUser is where i put the userID .

```
//Score for single user

    final RequestControllerObserver observer2 = new RequestControllerObserver() {


        public void requestControllerDidReceiveResponse(final RequestController requestController) {
            // get the scores from our controller
            ScoresController scoresController = (ScoresController) requestController;
            List<Score> scores = scoresController.getScores();


            if(scores!=null){



                for (Score score2 : scores) {
                    PointsText.setText(" "+ScoreFormatter.format(score2));
                    RankText.setText(" "+score2.getRank());

                }





                // we're done!
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
            }

        }


        public void requestControllerDidFail(final RequestController aRequestController, final Exception anException) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);

        }
    };

    // set up a ScoresController with our observer
    ScoresController scoresController = new ScoresController(null,observer2);


    showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);


    scoresController.setMode(0);

    scoresController.setRangeLength(1);

    scoresController.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession().getUser());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ScoresController scoresController = (ScoresController) requestController;

ScoresController scoresController = new ScoresController(null,observer2);
```

these are not the same, you are creating a local `ScoresController` in the first one.